# Form inside a hidden div has no values on post

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a html form that posts to a new page on submit. If required a user can click a button to make a small table visible in a div box. this adds more text input fields to my form.

The problem is, regardless of the div box being hidden or visible none of the additional fields data is sent when the form is posted .

the div box code

```
      function quotevisi()
  {
  document.getElementById("quote").style.visibility = "visible";
  tdat = "" ;
  tdat += "<h2 align='center' >Client Quotation </h2>" ;

  tdat += "<table align='center'cellpadding='1'  width='690px'><tr>"
  tdat += "<td ></td><td>Additional 1</td>" ;
  tdat += "<td ><label><textarea id='line1' cols='50' rows='1'>"
  tdat += "</textarea></label></td></tr>" 

  tdat += "<td ></td><td >Additional 2 </td>" ;
  tdat += "<td ><label><textarea id='line2' name='line2' cols='50' rows='1'>"
  tdat += "</textarea></label></td></tr>"

  tdat += "<td ></td><td >Additional 3 </td>" ;
  tdat += "<td ><label><textarea id='line3' name='line3' cols='50' rows='1'>"
  tdat += "</textarea></label></td></tr>"

  tdat += "<td ></td><td >Special Instructions</td>" ;
  tdat += "<td ><label><textarea id='special' name='special' cols='50' rows='1'>"
  tdat += "</textarea></label></td></tr>"

  tdat += "<td ></td><td ></td> <td>" ;
  tdat += "<input type='button' value='View Quote'          onclick='view_quote()'            />  "

  tdat += "<input type='button' value='Close' onclick='closequote()' />  " 

  tdat += "<td ></td> " ;

  tdat += "</table> "

  // display in the quote div (style sheet) 
  document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML= tdat
  }
```

The form is a bit big to but the button for the hidden field is this

```
<td ><input class="buttn" type="button" value="Extra Quote details "   onclick="quotevisi();" /> </td>
```

I would of thought that all this information would go with the form on post . But it doesent. Oh finally the div box code is placed after this line

```
<form  style='background-color:ccc' id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='process.php' >
```

Any help or thoughts would be much appreciated

thanks Mick

Comment: Can you add an excerpt of your actual HTML which shows where the <form> element fits in and where the element with the id 'quote' exists.

Comment: @Mick: Glad Bialecki figured it out. Do be sure to test this on IE if there's a chance you'll have IE users; adding form elements in this way is a known issue in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have to guess the form doesn't included the "quote" element, but what would really be helpful is a more complete snippet of HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . I had the <div id= 'quote'></div> before the form tag. as soon as I placed it after the form it worked a treat !

thanks all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Adding form elements via `innerHTML` is (unfortunately) unreliable, particularly in IE. (Table rows and such also have this problem.) [This page](http://domscripting.com/blog/display/99) lists a clever little workaround. Most JavaScript libraries (like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library/), ...) will do workarounds for you, FWIW.

The *visibility* of the form fields (e.g., whether they're inside a hidden div) shouldn't make any difference to their being submitted with the form. Of course, *disabled* form fields aren't submitted, but I don't get the impression you're disabling them.